# how to save image onSaveInstanceState when rotate screen ?

Tags: imageview, instance

I'm downloading an image to image view by AsyncTask and I want to save my image when I'm rotate my phone and not to download again to image view...

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle toSave) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(toSave);
    my_image.buildDrawingCache();
    Parcelable bm = my_image.getDrawingCache();
    toSave.putParcelable("savedImage", bm);

}
```

i'm trying to understand if I'm doing something wrong with  **onSaveInstanceState** or not, and how do I retrieve this state **onRestoreInstanceState** and place the image without downloading again ...

Answer (score 7):

onSaveInstanceState() function has to be used for saving small objects, not for heavy objects.

**If you want to save heavy images on phone rotation, then use any of below techniques:**

1. If you want to save large objects use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() function.
2. Or else we can make that image as static, so that the image will be loaded only once.
   Meaning: On downloading an image from network, make it pointed by a static variable.
   If user rotates the phone, since android kills that activity and recreates it, just
   put a if condition check if that static variable is not null, then only download again.
   As you know static variables will be created only once, it will not download again.

But preferably go for 1st option.

Ref : [developer android official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

Comment: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() function deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `super.onSaveInstanceState(toSave)` should be at the last place in method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle toSave)`.

In `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` check, if `savedInstanceState` is not null and get what you want:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        ...
        ...savedInstanceState.getParcerable(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static variables to hold onto bitmaps.